# How to highlight code in emacs in such a way that highlight doesn't get updated with point?

Tags: emacs

1. Keep a mark (C-space)
2. Move the point and highlight the code required

After this if u press (C-Space) then mark gets reset and highlight goes off. Or If I move the point then highlight also gets updated.

Comment: What is the end goal? Do you plan to do something to the region (the part that is shown as selected)?

Comment: You did not ask a question. Quite unclear what you want. If you want help then you will do well to make clear what you are trying to do and how what you see does not fit your expectation.